# Angular 2 - call function after change

Tags: angular, service

I want to call the `getCartSum()` function after the `addToCart(cartItem)` added the item to the cart so I receive the new "total" value of the cart.

here is my Service:

```
public cartItems: any[] = [];
public total: number;

constructor() {}

addToCart(cartItem) {
    this.cartItems.push(cartItem);
}

getCart() {
    return this.cartItems;
}

getCartSum() {
    this.total = 0;
    if (Object.keys(this.cartItems).length != 0) {
        for (var x of this.cartItems) {
            this.total += x.product.price;
        }
        return this.total;  
    }
    return this.total;
}
```

and here my ShoppingCart Component:

```
export class ShoppingCart  {
public title: string = "ShoppingCart";
public cartItems: any[];
public total: number;

constructor(private _cartService: CartService) {
    this.cartItems = this._cartService.getCart()
    this.total = this._cartService.getCartSum()
}

getCartSum() {
    this.total = this._cartService.getCartSum()
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to store the `_cartService` variable in the constructor of `ShoppingCart` to local member property so that it's accessible in the `getCartSum` method?

Comment: hm, I want that the "total" value will automatically updated when an Item is added to the cart. At the moment I have to call the method manualy in the Service to receive the new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) in your service:

```ts
private _totalChangeSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
totalChange$ = this._totalChangeSource.asObservable();
```

Have your component subscribe to the observable to be notified of changes:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._cartService.totalChange$.subscribe(
       newTotal => this.total = newTotal);
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

When you add an item, emit an event on the BehaviorSubject:

```ts
addToCart(cartItem) {
    this.cartItems.push(cartItem);
    this.updateTotal();
}
updateTotal() {
  this.total = 0;
  if (Object.keys(this.cartItems).length != 0) {
     for (var x of this.cartItems) {
        this.total += x.product.price;
     }
  }
  this._totalChangeSource.next(this.total);
}
```

Comment: thx for you answer, this work´s!
I also resolved my problem with: 
`<td class="collapsing">{{_cartService.getCartSum() | currency:'EUR':true:'1.2-2'}}</td>`
or is this not a good solution ???

Comment: @larz, using `getCartSum()` in the template is less efficient, since the method will be executed each time change detection runs.  Using observables, the total is only calculated when the cart contents changes.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?: 
Service:

```
addToCart(cartItem) {
    this.cartItems.push(cartItem);
    return this.getCartSum();
}
```

Component:

```
addToCart() {
    this.total = this._cartService.addToCart()
}
```